# in python How to add to the windows path variable to find executables

Tags: python, linux, windows

I have been looking for a way to make python search in folders that may not be listed in the windows path. This way I can account for some non standard locations for installed apps if they decide not to install it under c:\program files. for instance if unix utils is installed on a d drive or something.

Rather than modifying the windows path all the time. I figured I could read the registry find the path it was installed in and then add that to the search path for that python instance and still find what I'm looking for. The issue is that I also need to take into account predefined subfolders that have standard naming also.

I have searched and most of what I find is related to modifying the python path and were python finds it modules and this is not really useful for this.

I have also some across sys.path.append but can't really find anything about whether or not this would work for this. I also read the documentation for os.path and it looked like join may work but it didn't really seem to fit for this need.

Is there something that I'm just not getting here or is this not possible to do.

One last thing it needs to be cross platform compatible. I can find my own paths and add them as needed but just need a way to add to the path.

Thanks

Comment: Why not call the program using the full hierarchical filename, rather than adding it to the search path?

Comment: Ah well as stated it is not always in the standard install path. So in windows i can read the install path from the registry and simply add to the path. I could also add to the windows path programmatically I suppose but thats not the preferable method. The other thing is I have many different command line apps running and it would be way easier to simply add to the path rather then recode everything. I suppose as another way around I could simply find the path and add it before each command but there again still recording things.

Comment: What do you mean "make python search in folders that may not be listed in the windows path"? Python doesn't search folders in the Window PATH environment variable and the only thing it searches for are modules. Python searches for modules in its own `sys.path` whose value is influenced by the settings of the PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH environment variables if they exist. `sys.path` can also be changed at runtime.

Comment: ok lets make this easy is there a way to modify the windows path variable. However I'm asking is there a way to get python to do the same things as modifying the windows path variable for when I want to find a executable with the python subprocess module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To temporarily add to the path, for example:

```
    import os
    import sys

    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        sep = ';'
    else:
        sep = ':'

    os.environ['PATH'] += sep + r'"C:\QA\Hello World"'
```

Note that on Windows environment variables are not case sensitive, but on UNIX they are.  This will only add the path for this process, and it's children.

When you come to run the program, you need to use a shell which will use %PATH% (or $PATH).

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen('hello.exe',shell=True) 
proc.wait()
```

Comment: `os.pathsep` could be used

Comment: yes this is more or less what I wanted. Does that take effect immediately. I know modifying the windows path for instance sometimes does not behave as expected. Thank you

Comment: Depends what you mean by "immediately".  You need to use a shell (as in the example) to re-examine %PATH% and run the program.

Comment: Also note that on Windows paths with spaces in them in the PATH environment variable don't need to be quoted, so `+ r'C:\QA\Hello World'` would be OK.